# Go-Ethereum (Geth) run error: flag provided but not defined: -http.port

Tags: go-ethereum

I use official tutorial to run Ethereum private network:
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/private-net
but the command :

```
geth --datadir="/home/user/1" -verbosity 6 --ipcdisable --port 30301 --http.port 8101 console 2>> /home/user/1/01.log
```

return error:

```
Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -http.port
```

WAIDW?

upd. : upgrading of geth fith problem

Comment: Hi there. Which version of Geth are you using?

Comment: You right. I upgrade geth and problem dissapeared

Comment: Perfect - glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names of the HTTP/RPC-related options were changed in Geth [v1.9.19](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.9.19) under #[21105](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/21105).

From:

```
  --rpc                  
  --rpcaddr value        
  --rpcport value        
  --rpcapi value         
  --rpc.gascap value     
  --rpccorsdomain value  
  --rpcvhosts value
```

To:

```
  --http                            
  --http.addr value                 
  --http.port value                 
  --http.api value                  
  --http.rpcprefix value            
  --http.corsdomain value           
  --http.vhosts value
```

Either update Geth, or use the `--rpcport` option instead. (I'd recommend the former.)